# Send Telegram message with link and image

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


TOKEN = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)    #create a new Telegram Bot object


tg_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
tg_itembtn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" GO ", 'http://google.it')
tg_markup.add(tg_itembtn1)

tg_message_to_send = "Hello!\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "This is a test"
tg_message_to_send = "Title\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Other text: €\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Text #2: €\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Text #3 %\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "► https://bit . ly/dsfini"
tg_message_to_send += "<a href='https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/tree_267376982_250.jpg?version=4.0.200'>&#8205;</a>"


bot.send_message('CHAT_ID_HERE', tg_message_to_send, parse_mode = 'HTML', reply_markup = tg_markup, disable_web_page_preview=False)
```

I would like to send a message to a Telegram group containing a link and an image attached to it.
The problem is that the above code doesn't send the image. After many tries, I found that if I omit the line containing the link https://bit . ly/dsfini, the image is being sent.

How can I send both the link and the image?

Note: I insert a space in the link due to stackoverflow policy.

Answer (score 2):

Most TG clients will display a preview for the first link that's included in the message. So moving that hidden hyperref to the start of the message should do the trick.

---

**EDIT**

Note that `tg_message_to_send = "Title\n\n"` overrides `tg_message_to_send`. Changing to

```
tg_message_to_send = "Hello!\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "<a href='https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/tree_267376982_250.jpg?version=4.0.200'>&#8205;</a>"
tg_message_to_send += "This is a test"
tg_message_to_send += "Title\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Other text: €\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Text #2: €\n"
tg_message_to_send += "Text #3 %\n\n"
tg_message_to_send += "► https://bit . ly/dsfini"
```

or simply

```
tg_message_to_send = (
    "Hello!\n\n"
    "<a href='https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/thumb/tree_267376982_250.jpg?version=4.0.200'>&#8205;</a>"
    "This is a test"
    "Title\n\n"
    "Other text: €\n"
    "Text #2: €\n"
    "Text #3 %\n\n"
    "► https://bit . ly/dsfini"
)
```

gives tha desired result for me.

Comment: I tried putting the image link to the top of the message, as you suggested.
It works, but not always. Sometimes the images doesn't appear, and I don't know why.

Comment: Ultimately, it's up to the client to display the preview or not. If you want to be sure that the image shows, I recommend to send it via `send_photo`

Comment: Is there a way to show the image under the text with send_photo?

Comment: how to display photo + caption is again the clients decision … the bot API has no option to ask the client to display the photo at the bottom. you can ofc send 2 messages, first the text and then the image